# Transactions revert for ropsten only

Tags: ropsten, 0x

We use 0x for swaps on ethereum-mainnet, avalanche-mainnet, and polygon-mainnet and all is generally working. Previously we would also use kovan for testing, but recently moved to  ropsten as 0x is turning off kovan support. It's unclear as to why, but every swap I make on ropsten fails with a reverted transaction (while all other networks seem to work fine).

Example txn:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe56cb8d6fa99a1d3538bb52dd7511bf5f20aeb291ba61c98b8219a19722f23a0

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add additional info: how are you creating your swap payload/what is your transaction looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies this is our fault. We had a mismatch between the API and the contracts on Ropsten.

This is now fixed. Thank you for alerting us to the issue.

[Here is a test](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc7f201cdd72887ebf98ff44058989d146fa0aa908408785fe9facbe58eb70779) transaction to confirm.